# Determine correct size of icons in menu of action bar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, menuitem

How can I exactly use the sizes of icons I put in the items of the action bar?
E.g. if I put width 50dp with left/right margins 5 will it behave the same in all devices?
What is the recommended approach for determining correct sizes when adding custom icons for menu items in action bar?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_action_bar.html

Answer (score 0):

The [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_action_bar.html) says that

> Action Bar icons should be 32-bit PNGs with an alpha channel for
>   transparency.

The finished action bar icon dimensions, corresponding to a given generalized screen density, are:

- ldpi: 18 x 18 px
- mdpi: 24 x 24 px
- hdpi: 36 x 36 px
- xhdpi: 48 x 48 px

To generate the drawable for all the densities, including also xxhdpi and xxxdpi, you can use [Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-actionbar.htm).